# Equation of a solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

There is a way to calculate the equation of a solid of revolution, without using trigonometry, that is, a way without adding one more parameter $\theta$, because I know that it can be done with $(x,f(x)\cos(\theta),f(x)\sin(\theta))$

Comment: which line is the graph revolved around?

Comment: On the x axis, that is, my question is directed, if there is an alternative way, without referring to the angle of rotation.

Comment: $y^2+z^2=f(x)^2$

Comment: @cineel: That sounds like an answer....